# how do I access the values from getSize function in react native

Tags: react-native

I've written this code within a .map method to get the size of the image if an image exists, but I can't figure out a way to actually use the values 'width' and 'height'. When I console.log imageDimensions, it returns undefined

```
let imageDimensions
if(item.imageRoutes.length > 0){
  Image.getSize(item.imageRoutes[0].fileLink, (width, height) => {
    imageDimensions = ([width, height])
  })
  console.log(index, imageDimensions)
}
```

Comment: If you want to have the imageDimensions as an object, you should do it this way `imageDimensions = {width, height}`, the longer form would be `imageDimensions = {width: width, height: height}`. The way you did it I'm not sure what you were trying do define the imageDimensions like

Comment: sorry there shouldn't be brackets around the returned array

Comment: Ah, ok, got it. And before initializing the imageDimensions, the width and the height are not undefined?

Answer (score 0):

`Image.getSize` returns its values asynchronously. So, you get `width` and `height` in the callback function where you set `imageDimensions`. If you wanted to log it, you'd have to move that code:

```
let imageDimensions
if(item.imageRoutes.length > 0){
  Image.getSize(item.imageRoutes[0].fileLink, (width, height) => {
    imageDimensions = {width, height};
    console.log(index, imageDimensions); //here
  })
}
```

In terms of actually using those values in react, you'll probably want to use a state variable for them. If you're using function components, for example, you'd want to do your `Image.getSize` call in a `useEffect` and then store the value using `useState`

**Update based on comment:**
Storing multiple image sizes in `useState`:

```
const [imageSizes, setImageSizes] = useState({})

//inside your useEffect, when you get a new image size (assuming width and height were returned from getSize and imageUri holds the URI to the image:

//then to check it later
const imageSize = imageSizes[imageUri]
setImageSizes(prevState => {...prevState, [imageUri]: {width, height}});
```

Comment: What if it was for an array of images, and you wanted to make an array of image sizes?

Comment: Same idea -- I updated my answer with some details about that that wouldn't fit in a comment